# Why do I need to use のに instead of ので？

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, usage, nuances

> 食べてばかりいるので、なんで太いじゃないだろう？？

I was told for this sentence I should use のに instead of ので. Why is のに better here? It seems like it changes the meaning from “so/since” to “even though”.

I wanted to say “I’m just always eating so why aren’t I fat?” because I was finding an example for してばかりいる (it was the first example that came to mind, shhh!!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are interpreting the English use of the word 'so' in your sentence literally as 'consequently', you are equating that to **ので**, but the result in your sentence doesn't follow the action/behavior. You can use **だから** in this sense, but **ので** doesn't really work this way. It is more logical.

**ので** shows a natural or expected cause and effect behavior. *'I eat, so I gain weight.'*.
**のに** shows that the effect is not consistent with the cause. *'I eat, but I don't gain weight?'*.

> A, therefore B (B logically follows from A) = **ので**
>   A, and yet B (B does not logically follow from A) = **のに**

'I'm just always eating so why aren't I fat?' basically says the same thing as 'Even though I'm always eating, why don't I gain weight.'  (The result of not gaining weight is not consistent with the action of eating constantly).

Finally, 「なんで太いじゃない？？」is incorrect.
「なんで太らないんだろう？？」would be best.
An i-adjective + じゃない is like saying, 'It is ____, isn't it.' Remove the final い and replace with く before adding ない (太くない).  太い is, however, used mainly for objects and not people, with 細{ほそ}い being its antonym.
When describing people, however, generally the present-progressive form is used to indicate being overweight or underweight: 太{ふと}っている・太{ふと}っていない // 痩{や}せている・痩{や}せていない.
For people (in the process of) gaining weight or losing weight the plain form is used: 太{ふと}る・太{ふと}らない and 痩{や}せる・痩{や}せない.